# Spring Boot say "Port 8080 was already in use" but Windows cmd find no process for 8080

Tags: spring, windows, spring-boot, port

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0s88.png)

when i try to run my Spring Boot project in IntelliJ,
it randomly fail to start project with above error

i open the cmd window and execute "netstat -ano | findstr 8080" for find some process that using 8080 port
but there is no such process

and this time, my spring boot project is not yet stopped exactly
even it shows the "APPLICATION FAILED" log.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05RUI.png)

when i click the red square shape "stop 'MyApplication'" button, then this project is really stopped.

i just can run this project by other port (not 8080)
or i reboot my computer, the Windows system... only then i can use the 8080 port.

but why this happening? and how can i use the 8080 port without rebooting computer?

Comment: Does this happen with any other port you specify? For example, let's say that you set everything up to use port 8090. Does the same error show up after a while?

Comment: yes. once it occure, then it is same with around 8080 like 8081, 8082, ...and so on. but i can use like 9080, 9090 port. i don't know why.